# Is it possible to pass a reference of a function (with specified parameter values) as an argument to another Python function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming, parameter-passing

Here is the working code, with which the results are desirable.

```
import numpy as np
import random

class DataGenerator():
    def __init__(self):
        self.constant_n = 5

    def create_info(self, criteria_func):
        n = self.constant_n
        output_placeholder = []

        for i in range(n):
            single_output = criteria_func()
            output_placeholder.append(single_output)

        return output_placeholder

class NumberGenerator():
    def __init__(self, min_range, max_range):
        self.min_range = min_range
        self.max_range = max_range

    def number_generator(self):
        return random.randint(self.min_range, self.max_range)

def helper_func():
    num_gen_obj = NumberGenerator(1, 3)
    return {
        'RANDOM_INT': np.random.choice([num_gen_obj.number_generator(), 
                                        num_gen_obj.number_generator(), 
                                        num_gen_obj.number_generator()])
    }

def main():
    dg_obj = DataGenerator()
    result = dg_obj.create_info(
        criteria_func=helper_func)
    print(result)
    # [{'RANDOM_INT': 2}, {'RANDOM_INT': 2}, {'RANDOM_INT': 2}, {'RANDOM_INT': 3}, {'RANDOM_INT': 3}]

main()
```

It gives me the desired `result`. However, in my real code, I don't want the `NumberGenerator` object to be instantiated within the `helper_func()` function. I like to control/specify the argument values to `NumberGenerator` in the `main()` function. For example, when `helper_func` is referenced as a value to `criteria_func`, I want to be able to specify 2 values which will be an input argument values to `NumberGenerator` when `helper_func()` is later called.

The following is kind of what I want, but with obvious syntax error:

```
import numpy as np
import random

class DataGenerator():
    def __init__(self):
        self.constant_n = 5

    def create_info(self, criteria_func):
        n = self.constant_n
        output_placeholder = []

        for i in range(n):
            single_output = criteria_func()
            output_placeholder.append(single_output)

        return output_placeholder

class NumberGenerator():
    def __init__(self, min_range, max_range):
        self.min_range = min_range
        self.max_range = max_range

    def number_generator(self):
        return random.randint(self.min_range, self.max_range)

def helper_func(param1, param2):
    num_gen_obj = NumberGenerator(param1, param2)
    return {
        'RANDOM_INT': np.random.choice([num_gen_obj.number_generator(), 
                                        num_gen_obj.number_generator(), 
                                        num_gen_obj.number_generator()])
    }

def main():
    dg_obj = DataGenerator()
    result = dg_obj.create_info(
        criteria_func=(helper_func__param1=1, helper_func__param1=3))
    print(result)

main()
```

The closest I can get it to work is by adding a `HelperClass` with a `helper_func`. But I still wonder if there is a way to do it without a class method?

```
import numpy as np
import random

class DataGenerator():
    def __init__(self):
        self.constant_n = 5

    def create_info(self, criteria_func):
        n = self.constant_n
        output_placeholder = []

        for i in range(n):
            single_output = criteria_func()
            output_placeholder.append(single_output)

        return output_placeholder

class NumberGenerator():
    def __init__(self, min_range, max_range):
        self.min_range = min_range
        self.max_range = max_range

    def number_generator(self):
        return random.randint(self.min_range, self.max_range)

class HelperClass():
    def __init__(self, num1, num2):
        self.num1 = num1
        self.num2 = num2

    def helper_func(self):
        num_gen_obj = NumberGenerator(self.num1, self.num2)
        return {
            'RANDOM_INT': np.random.choice([num_gen_obj.number_generator(), 
                                            num_gen_obj.number_generator(), 
                                            num_gen_obj.number_generator()])
        }

def main():
    dg_obj = DataGenerator()
    helper_obj = HelperClass(1, 3)
    result = dg_obj.create_info(
        criteria_func=helper_obj.helper_func)
    print(result)

main()
```

Comment: just partially apply the arguments, an easy way is to pass `lambda : my_func(arg1=x, arg2=y)`. Or even just `def _callback(): return my_func(arg1=x, arg2=y)` then pass `_callback`. in either case, just be careful that `x` and `y` will be closed over the variables in the scope you create the function, and if they change, it will change in the closure as well.

Comment: The other option is to re-design `create_info` to take `def create_info(self, criteria_func, *criteria_args, **criteria_kwargs): ...` and then call the callback like: `single_output = criteria_func(*criteria_args, **criteria_kwargs)` then in main just `dg_obj.create_info(criteria_func, 1, 3)`

Answer (score 2):

It's relatively easy if you know how to unpack a tuple. You can pass the function reference and all its parameters as a tuple, then unpack everything. That way, you don't even need to know how many parameters the "criteria_func" function requires. Here's what i did:

as requested, helper func now has 2 parameters.

```py
def helper_func(param1, param2):
    num_gen_obj = NumberGenerator(param1, param2)
    return {
        'RANDOM_INT': np.random.choice([num_gen_obj.number_generator(), 
                                        num_gen_obj.number_generator(), 
                                        num_gen_obj.number_generator()])
    }
```

Main send these parameters using a tuple containing the function.

```py
def main():
    dg_obj = DataGenerator()
    result = dg_obj.create_info(
        criteria_func=(helper_func, 1, 3)) # sending the whole package here
    print(result)
```

And now, create_info can unpack them

```py
def create_info(self, criteria_func):
        n = self.constant_n
        output_placeholder = []

        for i in range(n):
            single_output = criteria_func[0](*criteria_func[1:]) # When this code is called, we do not know how many parameters there are, and we do not care!
            output_placeholder.append(single_output)

        return output_placeholder
```

criteria_func[0] is our function reference in `(helper_func, 1, 3)`
criteria_func[1:] is a slice of all the items after our function reference.

By adding a `*` we unpack this slice, effectively transforming `[1, 3]` in `1, 3` and passing them to helper_func, obtaining `helper_func(1, 3)`

Notice how this code does not take into account the case if criteria_func does not have any parameter. That should be trivial to fix.

Full code:

```py
import numpy as np
import random

class DataGenerator():
    def __init__(self):
        self.constant_n = 5

    def create_info(self, criteria_func):
        n = self.constant_n
        output_placeholder = []

        for i in range(n):
            single_output = criteria_func[0](*criteria_func[1:])
            output_placeholder.append(single_output)

        return output_placeholder

class NumberGenerator():
    def __init__(self, min_range, max_range):
        self.min_range = min_range
        self.max_range = max_range

    def number_generator(self):
        return random.randint(self.min_range, self.max_range)

def helper_func(param1, param2):
    num_gen_obj = NumberGenerator(param1, param2)
    return {
        'RANDOM_INT': np.random.choice([num_gen_obj.number_generator(), 
                                        num_gen_obj.number_generator(), 
                                        num_gen_obj.number_generator()])
    }

def main():
    dg_obj = DataGenerator()
    result = dg_obj.create_info(
        criteria_func=(helper_func, 1, 3))
    print(result)
    # [{'RANDOM_INT': 2}, {'RANDOM_INT': 2}, {'RANDOM_INT': 2}, {'RANDOM_INT': 3}, {'RANDOM_INT': 3}]

main()
```

Edit: as pointed out by juanpa.arrivillaga, a lambda could be another solution: you prepare the function beforehand and ignore all its parameters.

Here's how it would look like.

main:

```py
def main():
    dg_obj = DataGenerator()
    result = dg_obj.create_info(
        criteria_func=(lambda : helper_func(1, 3)))
    print(result)
    # [{'RANDOM_INT': 2}, {'RANDOM_INT': 2}, {'RANDOM_INT': 2}, {'RANDOM_INT': 3}, {'RANDOM_INT': 3}]
```

create_info:

```
def create_info(self, criteria_func):
        n = self.constant_n
        output_placeholder = []

        for i in range(n):
            single_output = criteria_func() #Notice how the lambda hides any kind of parameters.
            output_placeholder.append(single_output)

        return output_placeholder
```